# Why does ICU have distinctions for "stand alone" values for dates?

Tags: icu

ICU has different formatting symbols for "stand alone" values.  For example:

```
q   Stand Alone quarter
L   Stand Alone month in year
c   Stand Alone local day of week
```

[The documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax) states:

> "Stand Alone" values refer to those designed to stand on their own, as opposed to being with other formatted values. "2nd quarter" would use the stand alone format (QQQQ), whereas "2nd quarter 2007" would use the regular format (qqqq yyyy).

However, this doesn't explain *why* there is a distinction.  I presume that this matters for some languages, but what are some examples?

(More confusingly, the documentation contradicts itself since it uses both `q` and `Q` for the stand alone version.)

I also presume that stand alone versions aren't needed for other fields (such as year, hour, minute, seconds) because those are numeric.  If that's the case, however, why do the stand alone values for weekday, month, and quarter support numeric forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distinction is relevant for ie Polish in which expressing day `dd MMMM yyyy`: *"22 września 2022"* is different than expressing just a month like ie in calendar `LLLL yyyy`: *"wrzesień 2022"*.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up filing [ICU-21225](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/ICU-21225) to correct the contradiction in the documentation and to ask for clarification.  One of the comments directed me to https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#months_days_quarters_eras, which states:

> The context is either *format* (the default), the form used within a complete date format string (such as "Saturday, November 12"), or *stand-alone*, the form for date elements used independently, such as in calendar headers. The most important distinction between format and stand-alone forms is a grammatical distinction, for languages that require it. For example, many languages require that a month name without an associated day number (i.e. an independent form) be in the basic *nominative* form, while a month name with an associated day number (as in a complete date format) should be in a different grammatical form: *genitive*, *partitive*, etc.

I'm still curious about specific examples (which languages?), though.